# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'EmailIsNotVerified' in 'field list' in /home/tsecret1/Test-Server/reg.php:19

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Для начала, ошибка:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'EmailIsNotVerified' in 'field list' in /home/tsecret1/Test-Server/reg.php:19`
Код:

```
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ts********ys", "FB********iu", "ts**********rs");
  mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, $charset);

//Переменные
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];
  $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
  $pass2_hash = hash("sha256", $pass2);
  $result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `Exiting Users` where email='Aruba';");
  if ($result->num_rows <= "1") {
    if ($pass == $pass2) {
      //Регистрация
      $link->query("INSERT INTO `Exiting Users`(`email`) VALUES (\"$email\")");
      $link->query("CREATE TABLE `tsecret1_users`.`\"$email\"` ( `PassWord` TEXT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MyISAM");
      $link->query("INSERT INTO `\"$email\"`(`PassWord`) VALUES (\"$pass2_hash\")");
      $link->query("ALTER TABLE `\"$email\"` ADD COLUMN `parameters` TEXT NOT NULL AFTER `PassWord`;");
      $link->query("INSERT INTO `\"$email\"` (`parameters`) VALUES (`EmailIsNotVerified`)");
    };
  }
?>
```

Почему возникает эта ошибка, и как её исправить?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать разные кавычки для «EmailIsNotVerified», так как символом кавычки идентификатора является обратная черта («` »). В противном случае MySQL «думает», что вы указываете на столбец с именем «EmailIsNotVerified».